# Vim File Explorer with include directory

Tags: vim, directory, include-path

I have been using Vim's file explorer plugin so that I can easily view files in my directory and open them by double clicking. This worked fine when I had all of my .h and .cpp in the same directory. But now I separated them. My .cpp files are in a src/ directory and my .h are in an include/ directory. So when I open Vim, the file explorer will only show one directory and I can't access both .h and .cpp. How can I make it show files from both directories? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tree style for netrw plugin. It will allow you to browse all subdirs of your project's dir.

To switch to it you can press "i" until it shows your directory as a tree (with a branch on the left). To make it permanent, you can add

```
let g:netrw_liststyle= 3
```

to your .vimrc file.

Comment: Thanks! It seems if I went up one directory, I could already access the include directory. But I have to go there before accessing the files in that directory. Should it be able to list all of the files at once so I can just click the file directly?

Comment: You can open parent directory with `:e ..`. Then you can select needed  subdir and a file. I'm not sure if there's a way to tell netrw to open all subdirs in the tree view. You can automate this somehow.

Comment: I personally prefer CtrlP.vim plugin. I always open files from project's dir and with simple Ctrl-P press I get access to all project files with smart matching and sorting.